# Text misalign when using resizebox

Tags: floats, tabularx

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Quotes won't work without babel
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % This is very important!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, breaklinks=true, pdftex=true, raiselinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\subsubsection{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YY}\hline

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\begin{enumerate}
\item  \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor}\\ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\item  \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor}\\ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\item  \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor}\\ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\\ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\item  \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor}\\Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{enumerate}
&\textbf{\centering \vspace{-10pt} \resizebox{.8\linewidth}{!}{\vspace{-10pt}          \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Lorem.png}} \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor}
}\tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{figure}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

When I set `\resizebox{\linewidth}`, the left column of the table aligns the text perfectly, but if I set `\resizebox{.8\linewidth}` the left side of the table, aligns the text at the point where the right side ends. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong in here, or maybe give me some tip, please?

What I see:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Why putting the `\includegraphics` inside a `\resizebox`? Just do `\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{...}`.

Comment: @egreg: You are right, but still the left side of the table is misaligned, when setting the \includegraphics{width=.8\linewidth}

Comment: What precisely do you want to attain?

Comment: @egreg: I want to have a 2 column table, with a text on the left side and a figure on the right side, to be both at the top of the page. Now only the right side with the figure is at the top, and the text is somewhere in the middle of left column.

Comment: You haven't shown what result you get or used an image that we can use so it is hard to tell what you are seeing. `\resizebox{.8\linewidth}{!}{\vspace{-10pt}          ` the vspace will be ignored (as it would be inside `\mbox`) and the white space will mean that the box is a word space wider than the image.

Comment: @David Carlisle: if I delete the vspace, nothing changes.

Comment: Well that's not a surprise because as I said, it will be ignored, but the following white space has an effect.  But we still don't know what you are seeing that you think is incorrect.

Comment: I added pictures, hope now you can visualize better what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Using the `[demo]` option to `graphicx` so it doesn't need the actual image file.

The image below fixes the spacing issues in the posted example. Note however that if teh actual code is as here just a single row two column `tabularx` It would be vastly more efficient, and easier to automatically get the vertical centering, if the table was not used and the graphic simply placed after a `\begin{minipage}[c]` containing the enumeration.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Quotes won't work without babel
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % This is very important!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, breaklinks=true, pdftex=true, raiselinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp!]
\subsubsection{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YY}\hline

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\begin{enumerate}
\item  \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor}\\ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\item  \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor}\\ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\item  \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor}\\ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\\ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\item  \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor}\\Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{enumerate}
&\centering 
\vspace*{10\baselineskip} 
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Lorem.png}
 \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor}\tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{figure}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```